# How to show latest blog post rather then earliest

Tags: blog

I have a Wordpress blog site that I am building.  My problem is that when the homepage loads it shows my earliest post from three years ago.  What I would like it for my most recent post to show instead. Can anyone tell me how I could accomplish this.  I have looked through several articles and none have a solution that work for me.  Here is the code I am using to load the post:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
<p><?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?></p>
<hr> <?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p><?php
endif; ?>
```

Comment: You will most probably need to look for a `pre_get_posts` action which is altering the main query on your homepage, either in your theme or in a plugin you are using.

Comment: Also, make sure that you do not have sticky posts set. Sticky posts will always appear as first posts on the homepage.

Answer (score -4):

There must be something playing with your query (using pre_get_posts) as the default in WP is to load the last created post.

Use this WP_Query instead

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=1&post_type=post' );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    ?>
    <h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
    <p><?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?></p>
    <?php
 } else {
  ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p><?php
  <?php
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: NOOOOOOOO!!!!!!, why do you want to do that. **NEVER** change the main query with custom one. This is a horrible solution which you should avoid. Sort the root of the issue, don't hide it with something which will later cause bigger issues

Comment: depends on what the ultimate goal is surely Peter? this solution gives them more scope to customise to get the post from a certain category, or to change other aspects of the query .....

Comment: @GarethGillman Then WP should remove its default query and ask everyone to build their query :P

Comment: This is bad solution why because some plugin/theme adding something and we are removing it. If we don't  want it then why to add ?

Comment: For every goal, there is `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query to suit your exact needs. There is even the `posts_clauses` filters which you can use to customize the main query. A custom query will never be solution as it runs extra unnecessary db queries, slows your page and ultimitely cause paging issues